# Returning rows that have a particular string where column is null, but also including lines where column is not null?

Tags: sql, teradata-sql-assistant

I am trying to pull information out of shipping notifications that are loaded into our system automatically when an order is shipped. I am hoping to grab the `BILL_OF_LADING` (BOL) and also the shipped qty (SHQ & number in `AUDIT_TRAIL_VERBAGE`). When there is a BOL in the line, the system automatically populates it in the BOL column.

| PO_NUMBER | AUDIT_TRAIL_VERBAGE | BILL_OF_LADING |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567 | **BOL 1234567890AB**/CAR FEDEX/ | 1234567890AB |
| 1234567 | **SHQ 00007**/UNT EA/ |  |

I think this logic needs to be in my `WHERE` statement (maybe as `CASE` statement?)  but I can't figure out how to get SQL to return the shipped QTY if the BOL column is null. It would also be great if I could grab the numbers following SHQ (it is always 5). Below is the last thing I tried, but the `OR` statement did not behave like I thought and took over the whole `WHERE` statement.

```
SELECT  PO_NUMBER,
        AUDIT_TRAIL_VERBAGE,
        BILL_OF_LADING

FROM MY.TABLE

WHERE 
       PO_NUMBER IN '1234567'
   AND BILL_OF_LADING IS NOT NULL
   OR AUDIT_TRAIL_VERBAGE LIKE 'SHQ%'
```

I am still learning, so any help or guidance would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged the post terradata, I am assuming that is the flavor of sql you are using.  The substring function is flavor specific.  Your WHERE clause is almost correct, all you need is parenthesis.

```
SELECT PO_NUMBER,
    BILL_OF_LADING,
    AUDIT_TRAIL_VERBAGE,
    CASE WHEN AUDIT_TRAIL_VERBAGE LIKE 'SHQ%'
         THEN SUBSTRING(AUDIT_TRAIL_VERBAGE 5 FOR 5)
         ELSE NULL
    END AS SHIPPED_QTY

FROM MY.TABLE 

WHERE 
   PO_NUMBER IN '1234567'
   AND (BILL_OF_LADING IS NOT NULL
   OR AUDIT_TRAIL_VERBAGE LIKE 'SHQ%')
```

Now if you want to get the info for one PO all on one line, you can do this:

```
SELECT SHQ.PO_NUMBER,
    BOL.BILL_OF_LADING
    SUBSTRING(SHQ.AUDIT_TRAIL_VERBAGE 5 FOR 5) AS SHIPPED_QTY

FROM MY.TABLE AS SHQ
LEFT JOIN MY.TABLE AS BOL ON SHQ.PO_NUMBER=BOL.PO_NUMBER 
                          AND BOL.BILL_OF_LADING IS NOT NULL
                          AND SHQ.AUDIT_TRAIL_VERBAGE LIKE 'SHQ%'
WHERE 
   PO_NUMBER IN '1234567'
```

Comment: Teradata syntax supports either `SUBSTR(SHQ.AUDIT_TRAIL_VERBAGE,5,5)` or `SUBSTRING(SHQ.AUDIT_TRAIL_VERBAGE FROM 5 FOR 5)` but not SUBSTR with FOR.

Comment: @Fred.  Fixed.  I had seen that in the documentation, I don't know why I didn't write it that way in the first place.

Comment: @BrianZ the first code works, but I would be great if it could be in one line like your second code. It gives me the 'SQL command not properly ended' error, its doesn't seem to like 'AS SHQ'